# Getting empty experiment run using mlflow databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow

I am trying to run the following code

```py
iter_max = 100
CC = 1
save_model = False
with mlflow.start_run(run_name=run_name, experiment_id=experiment.experiment_id, nested=True) as run:
    text_clf = Pipeline([
        ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf',LogisticRegression(max_iter=iter_max, C=CC))])
    text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    run_id = mlflow.active_run().info.run_id`
```

But I get no model and no dataset...

[image]

I would like to get a model so I can register it and use it on databricks

I would like to get a model, register it and use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the model like below. Use below code.

```
save_model = True
with mlflow.start_run(run_name=run_name, experiment_id=experiment_id, nested=True) as run:
    text_clf = Pipeline([
        ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', LogisticRegression(max_iter=iter_max, C=CC))
    ])
    text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


    if save_model:
        mlflow.sklearn.log_model(text_clf, "model")

    mlflow.log_param("iter_max", iter_max)
    mlflow.log_param("CC", CC)

    run_id = mlflow.active_run().info.run_id

if save_model:
    mlflow.register_model(f"runs:/{run_id}/model", "My Registered Model")
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

You can use below code for prediction.

```
import mlflow
logged_model = 'runs:/{run_id}/model'

# Load model as a PyFuncModel.
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)

# Predict on a Pandas DataFrame.
import pandas as pd
loaded_model.predict(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

You can also see the model in **models** section.

[image]